# Method does not await for fetch to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using [Node Ytdl](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core) in order to obtain metadata of videos. I have a 'provider' function which I want to return the metadata object of a video.

```
const getMetaD = async (mediaID) => {
   let obj = {};

   await ytdl.getInfo(mediaID, {}, async (err, info) => {
       if (err) console.log(err);

       let format = await ytdl.chooseFormat(info.formats, { quality: 'highest' });

       if (format) {
         console.log('Format found!', format);
         obj = { url: format.url, thumbnail: info.thumbnail, title: info.title };
       }
     });

  return obj;
}
```

However, my `getMetaD` function never returns the object assigned in the `if(format)` block. It will always return the `obj = {}`. What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't my code await for the results to be assigned to `obj` before returning it?

Comment: You're probably `await`ing `undefined` instead of a Promise. Does `ytld.getInfo` really accept a callback and also return a Promise to `await`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using await on a callback. It only works on promises. You can achieve the same thing by doing this though.

```
const getMetaD = (mediaID) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           let obj = {};

       ytdl.getInfo(mediaID, {}, async (err, info) => {
           if (err) console.log(err);

           let format = await ytdl.chooseFormat(info.formats, { quality: 'highest' });

           if (format) {
             console.log('Format found!', format);
             obj = { url: format.url, thumbnail: info.thumbnail, title: info.title };
           }
           resolve(obj);
         });
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ytdl.getInfo` will return a Promise **if** you don't pass in a callback

So, you would rewrite your code as follows (no error checking here, but then you don't do any in your code either)

```
const getMetaD = async (mediaID) => {
    let obj = {};
    const info = await ytdl.getInfo(mediaID, {});
    const format = await ytdl.chooseFormat(info.formats, { quality: 'highest' });
    if (format) {
        console.log('Format found!', format);
        obj = { url: format.url, thumbnail: info.thumbnail, title: info.title };
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. To be fair [type definition](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/blob/3857628303029a8586e34048039cf8455ae7bae5/typings/index.d.ts#L244-L245) shows `getInfo()` always returns a promise, but as you can see only does if callback isn't defined https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/blob/3857628303029a8586e34048039cf8455ae7bae5/lib/info.js#L346